# What 'Customer mode' when calling cart_customer.set with SOAP api?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, checkout, customer

I'm using the SOAP V1 api and attempting to set the customer. My site does not have a customer login, so I want to set the customer mode as guest. . . exactly as is done in the [example in the docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.set.html) for this call.

I'm using node and [MagentoJS](https://github.com/mayconheerdt/MagentoJS) to connect to my store; my customer array is:

```
    var customerArray = [{
        'firstname'     : 'test',
        'lastname'      : 'user',
        'email'         : 'test.user@gmail.com',
        'mode'          : 'guest',
        'entity_id'     : '5'
    }];
```

The error that I keep getting is:

```
[Error: XML-RPC fault: Customer's mode is unknown]
  code: 1045,
  faultCode: 1045,
  faultString: 'Customer\'s mode is unknown'
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Do I need to set up the mode elsewhere previously? And the entity_id? If so, where does that happen?

Comment: what is entity_id you are using? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: I have no idea what entity_id is to tell the truth. I put it in and played with different numbers to see if it did anything, but, to my sadness, it did not.

Comment: if you are in mode guest, why do you need any entity_id, just skip it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hired a magento expert and the solution was to make the customer array as such. . .

{ firstname: 'test',
  lastname: 'user',
  email: 'test.user123@gmail.com',
  website_id: '1',
  store_id: '1',
  mode: 'guest' }

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: How does that differ to the version in your question?

Comment: What if the user is logged in already ?? The mode can't be guest all the time ??

Answer (score 3):

If the user is logged in then you have to set the customer mode to

> customer

```
$customer = array( 'entity_id' => 6, 'mode' => 'customer' );
```